# Is there is anyway to update the text-input in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am using text input in react-native,now my requirement is that i want to update my Text-Input at same time while user type something like "Hello" and get altered in some other language and set over there.How can i set my new text on text-input while at typing?

Answer (score 0):

dynamically translating letters, i dont think makes sense as even if you use an API or some node module for translation how would it get to know what the user is going to end with typing, there is no letter to letter mapping possible untill you donot want it to make sense explicitly.
do you get what i am trying to say?